# How did 'fast' shift semantically from 'firm' to 'quick'?

Tags: etymology

I chanced on the following explanation on Aug. 5 2018, 2 years and 5 months after I initially posted this. Anyone have anything to add to or buttress it?

McWhorter, J. [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter). [*The Language Hoax* (2016)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006052085X). pp. 123-124.

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for including your conjecture so that we can respond to it. I think the derivation is probably mainly from "vigor." A vigorous and strong person can move more quickly than a weak person. We can compare the development of "quick" (which originally meant "alive" or "lively") and "speed" (which originally meant "success" or "prosperity.")

Comment: [http://www.etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fast)

Comment: @sumelic +1. Thanks. You are welcome; at least I managed to conjecture this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of ***[fast](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fast&allowed_in_frame=0)*** meaning quickly, rapidly etc. was already present in OE and  appears to derive from a Scandinavian usage:

> - ***The meaning "quickly, swiftly, rapidly" was perhaps in Old English, certainly by c. 1200, probably from or developed under influence of Old Norse fast "firmly, fast."***
> - ***This sense developed, apparently in Scandinavian, from that of "firmly, strongly, vigorously"***  (to run hard means the same as to run fast; also compare fast asleep, also compare Old Norse drekka fast "to drink hard," telja fast "to give (someone) a severe lesson").
> - ***Or perhaps from the notion of a runner who "sticks" close to whatever he is chasing*** (compare Old Danish fast "much, swiftly, at once, near to, almost," and sense evolution of German fix "fast, fixed; fast, quick, nimble," from Latin fixus).

(Etymonline)

Comment: That would make sense. "Fast" as in "fasting" or "abstaining from food" also existed in pre-12th century OE, and compliments the "firm" or "stoutly" definition. The two words coexisted instead of being supplanted.